# Orbit around selection not working on some Objects?

Tags: navigation

I`m using Blender2.8 and depending on the object I select Orbit around Selection does not seem to work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mK2A3g2DjRU&feature=youtu.be

Any idea what could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to try .. go to the object's properties > Viiewport Display panel, and check 'Bounds'. The view orbit is based on the selection's bounding box.. even one stray vertex will recenter it.

Comment: Thanks!. learned something new again. Bounds revealed a stray vertex indeed which solved the issue (as all planes were copies the stray vertex persisted in all of them)

Answer (score 2):

It just happened to me, and I found that the view port camera target was accidentally locked to an object (in my case to one of the lights) so navigating was a nightmare. Go to View tab, under View section, View Lock subsection and uncheck options and clear the 'Lock to object' field. Hope that would solve it.
Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by unchecking *Navigation > Orbit Around Selection* in the *Preferences*.